# Useful UI control for ManyToMany relationships in Angular

Tags: angular, user-interface, controls, many-to-many

Are there any handy UI controls for managing ManyToMany relationships, that can be used in Angular applications?

In former days we created this by hand, using two multiselect comboboxes with 4 arrow controls for managing the relationsship.

What is state of the art today? :-)

Thank you in advance
Harald